# The forwarding robot code based on telethon can run but does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

```
import telethon
api_id = XX
api_hash = 'XX'
client = telethon.TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
async def main():
    await client.connect()
    me = await client.get_me()
    chat_id = me.id
    while True:
        messages = await client.get_messages(chat_id)
        for message in messages:
            if "vi_" in message.text or "ai_" in message.text:
                await client.forward_messages('user', message.id)
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When I sent a message containing vi_ or ai_, the robot did not forward it.

I want the robot to receive a new message containing vi_ or ai_ and immediately forward it to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Telethon v1, `with` already calls `start()` (which `connect()`s). There is no need to `connect()` inside the `async def`.

You have an endless loop constantly getting the latest message. This is likely to lead to flood waits. You probably want to [use events instead](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/updates.html).

`forward_messages` often needs to know where to forward the message from. You can specify that as the third parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation! I've optimized and got my code working